# How can I refactor these variables in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Im learning React.js and Im not sure on the best way to do the following:

I have the following React class ( stripped down for simplicity )

```
const X01Game = React.createClass({


saveShot(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentPlayer = this.props.players[this.state.currentPlayer],
          currentID     = currentPlayer.ID,
          shot          = this.refs.shot.value;
       .... shot saved.....
},
isValidShot( shot ) {
    const currentPlayer = this.props.players[this.state.currentPlayer],
          currentID     = currentPlayer.ID,
          score         = this.state.score[currentID];
    .... shot validated.....
},

render() {

    return (
        <div className="game-container">
            .... render game ....
        </div>  
    );
}
});

export default X01Game;
```

As you can see in several methods I repeat this:

```
    const currentPlayer = this.props.players[this.state.currentPlayer],
      currentID     = currentPlayer.ID,
      shot          = this.refs.shot.value;
```

There is any way I can declare these globally so avoid repeating on each method? Doesn't look right to me like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're always requesting the `currentPlayerId`, just add a method to the `X01Game class` that will get it:

```
getGurrentPlayerId() {
    var currentPlayer = this.props.players[this.state.currentPlayer];
    return currentPlayer ? currentPlayer.id : null; // in case the player doesn't exist
}
```

The same goes for shot:

```
getShot() { // pun intended 
    return this.refs.shot && this.refs.shot.value;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
saveShot(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentID     = this.getGurrentPlayerId(),
          shot          = this.getShot();
       .... shot saved.....
},
isValidShot( shot ) {
    const currentID     = this.getGurrentPlayerId(),
          score         = this.state.score[currentID];
    .... shot validated.....
},
```

Comment: I don't think this would be ideal, now he has two additional methods added with no code reduction, you just abstracted where the data is being fetched from

Comment: The abstractions are DRY, as they can be used multiple times, without repeating yourself. The `getGurrentPlayerId` also encapsulates the logic of getting the `currentPlayerId`, so you can skip finding the `currentPlayer` before getting it's id (2 lines instead of 4).

Comment: Thanks @OriDrori this was going to be my next natural step, I was just wondering if we could set something more global like when you set variables on the constructor of a PHP class

Comment: Also fyi I need the current player because later I use it for the name . I will wait a couple of days to see if anyone else answer or accept yours. Thanks again